# Firebreath: binary string return value exception

Tags: npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

I have a piece of code that gets random binary string from CAPICOM.Utilities.

```
m_pUtilities.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Utilities));
_bstr_t bstrResult;
m_pUtilities->raw_GetRandom(64, CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY, bstrResult.GetAddress());
```

I made a method that returns

```
return std::wstring(bstrResult);
```

My method crashes plugin appr. 1 of 6 calls. The exception description is 
*Unhandled exception at 0x7572969b in chrome.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: utf8::invalid_utf16 at memory location*.
I tried to change return type of my method from FB::variant to std::wstring, but this didn't help.

What I did wrong? How should I return the binary string? Converting the binary string to base64 or other changes in return string is not suitable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass this as a string to JavaScript you really need to use `CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64` - otherwise the values in this buffer could be anything, including values outside the character space. Some code obviously checks for this, causing your exception.

If you only need to use this internally in your plugin, don't use strings but e.g. a `std::vector<WCHAR>` or just use the `BSTR`.

*Side note:* it won't matter in this case, but `BSTR`s are length prefixed and both `BSTR`s and `std::wstring`s can contain embedded `0`s - so to be correct you really would have to return `std::wstring(bstr.GetBSTR(), bstr.length())`.

Comment: Yeah; you can't return binary strings from an npapi plugin to the browser, it's just not supported. The browsers expect a utf8-encoded string

Comment: Unfortunately I need to pass this value out of my plugin. Probably I will not implement this option at all.

Comment: @Pisaren: Technically you could fill a (JS) array with the plain values and return that, but that would be very slow. How about passing it as base64 to JS and decode it to a number array there?

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: I wanted to implement different return types(binary or base64 string) defined by input parameter, so now I will return base64 strings only.